# How to make an array/vector of pairs of 2 corresponding integers from 2 different user input lines in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

How to pair up corresponding elements from two different input lines, to form one array of pairs in C++ ?

Eg. input :

```
0 1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8 9

output = [{0,5} {1,6} {2,7} {3,8} {4,9}]
```

Edit :
Input is given by the user through stdin and not in the form of 2 different arrays.
I want to store this input directly in the form of an array of pairs without first creating 2 arrays then making pairs.

Edit 2: I'm just looking avoid use of any additional space for intermediate steps. I tried the following, but it doesn't give me the correct output.

```
vector<pair<int, int>> pairs;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> k;
        pairs.push_back({k, 0});
    }
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> k;
        pairs[i] = {pairs[i].first, k};
    }
```

TIA.

Comment: Why not a simple `for` loop? You may try to post an example of such a simple implementation, so that we can react on it

Comment: @Damien the input is not in the form of already created arrays but is entered by the user. I want to store this data in the form of an array of pairs, without first having to create 2 arrays to store the input then form pairs.

Comment: Why does the first line of the question say that the data is in two arrays, but the edit says they're not in arrays?

Comment: Either it's in arrays or it isn't, the question shouldn't describe two different problems.

Comment: May I ask what your reason is to do that efficiently? Efficiently is for something like computing billions of things after each other. If you implement it inefficiently (and prioritize things like readability), anything required to sort things out will still be done  the moment the user withdrew his finger from the return key.

Comment: @Aziuth I suspect he meant efficiency in coding, i.e. simplicity, not performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revising your attempt, you should update the pair in the second loop rather than replacing it.

```
vector<pair<int, int>> pairs;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cin >> k;
    pairs.emplace_back(k, 0);
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cin >> pairs[i].second;
}
```

Comment: Is this much different from storing the input into 2 arrays first?

Comment: @Karmah24 You have to save the first line somewhere. But it saves you from having to write loops to turn the lines into arrays.

Comment: I've made an edit, showing what I tried, could you suggest something along these lines, and maybe point out why what I tried doesn't work?

Comment: In the second loop, you could just do `pairs[i].second = k;` instead of creating a new pair. Otherwise the first set of pairs are the extra space for the intermediate values.

Comment: Your method requires you to know how many items are on each line. Is that assured?

Answer (score 2):

<sup>This is a revised answer since the question has changed a lot.</sup>

If the size is known, create the resulting `vector<pair<int, int>>` with the correct size from the start, then use two range based for-loops with structured bindings to fill it.

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> res(number_of_pairs);

for(auto&[a, b] : res) if(!(std::cin >> a)) return 1;
for(auto&[a, b] : res) if(!(std::cin >> b)) return 1;
```

Comment: I'm sorry my question wasn't clear before, I've made some edits. The input is being entered by the user. and I want to store it directly in the form of an array of pairs instead of first creating 2 arrays and then forming pairs.

Comment: @Karmah24 So, you could make the user enter `0 5` `1 6` etc?

Comment: @Karmah24 I was away and didn't have a chance to react to the changed question (which is why I probably got a downvote). I added a third version now.